# mixture distribution cannot be described by a PDF?

Tags: probability

[On Wikipedia about a random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable), it states:

> Not all continuous random variables are absolutely continuous, for example a mixture distribution. Such random variables cannot be described by a probability density or a probability mass function.

However, both a [mixture distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) and a [compound probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution) can be described by a probability density or a probability mass function.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Either a) you work with pdfs, and some people will accept  **functions** but not **distributions** (the name given to "generalized functions", here with dirac $w_k\delta(x-k)$s). or b) you work with cdfs, and no such problem arise : a cdf is an increasing function that can be continuous or possess jumps... where, by (generalized) derivation, the  $w_k\delta(x-k)$s are situated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two issues here:

- a mixture distribution combining a continuous random variable and a discrete random variable cannot be described as just having a probability density function or just having a probability mass function.  For example a mixture of a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$ and a Bernoulli random variable might have cdf $F(x)=0$ when $x \lt 0$, $F(x)=\frac{2x+1}4$ when $0 \le x \lt 1$, $F(x)=1$ when $ x \ge 1$.  But this would not be a continuous random variable
- a [singular distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_distribution) can represent a continuous random variable which is not absolutely continuous and does not have a density.  An example would be a [Cantor distributed random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution)

These two particular cdfs look like this (neither curve has a derivative everywhere but there are regions where both are continuous)

[image]